Pylance throwing errors in state machine implementation : "sysCheck" is incompatible with "ResetState"PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue
Im trying to make a statemachine in python (I know there is a module, im trying not to use those) and it is giving me an error for the reassignment, and I was wondering if I even needed to worry about it:
  Expression of type "ResetState | sysCheck" cannot be assigned to member "currState" of class "Globals"
    Member "set" is unknown
    Type "ResetState | sysCheck" cannot be assigned to type "ResetState"
      "sysCheck" is incompatible with "ResetState"PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue 

So the code I have is in 2 files
Globals.py

from StateMachine import States
class Globals:
    states = States()
    currState = states.ResetStateObject

StateMachine.py
from Globals import Globals
class States:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ResetStateObject = self.ResetState()
            self.sysCheckObject = self.sysCheck()

    class ResetState:
        def transistion_function(self):
            return
        def run_function(self):
            return Globals.states.sysCheckObject

    class sysCheck:
        def transistion_function(self):
            return
        def run_function(self):
            return Globals.states.sysCheckObject

class StateMachine:
    def __init__(self):
         self.new_state = Globals.states.ResetStateObject


    def tick(self): ## run this in a loop to run the statemachine ||
            if Globals.currState == self.new_state:
                self.new_state  = Globals.currState.run_function()
            else:
                Globals.currState = self.new_state
                Globals.currState.transition_function()

The question is if I can just ignore that error
I want to assign the object of the class with the same function names, and make it simple to read in the main function
I was not able to test it, since it is supposed to run on micropython, and a lot of the supporting code is note ready yet. However I think it should be fine but I was not able to figure out myself if I need to look at classes a different way than I'm doing now
the error is on the line

Globals.currState = self.new_state


I was wrond in my previous awnser, however it was fixed using enums

This should be a comment on your incorrect answer.
